# Using PHP to read text from a PDF stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, text

I am trying to use PHP to read the text from a PDF file that is stored in a mysql database. I tried using class.pdf2text.php, which works with an actual file. I tried to use the MYSQL_RESULT variable with the pdf file contents with that class, but it doesn't work. I've got to be missing something really easy, I just know it.

Basically, this is what I'm trying to do: 
I have a database with PDF files. I need to convert a PDF from that database to text and then  search on that text for certain data. Is there a way to do this without creating external files in PHP?

Comment: I think the closest thing you will be able to do is user temp files - but I think you still need to use a file because most likely the `class.pdf2text.php` is using poppler/xpdf/ghostscript to read the text in the pdf and they need to act on files.

Comment: class.pdf2text.php actually isn't going to work for me, since these appear to be more intricate pdf files than it can handle. pdftotext works great on these files. The problem I'm having though, is that I have the file contents in a variable, but I can't pass that to the exec command for pdftotext, since it's expecting an actual file, not file contents. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you have the binary PDF contents in a variable - write out the file contents with `file_put_contents()` to a temp file and then you can run `pdftotext` on the temp file. make sure you `unlink()` the temp file when complete.

Comment: Yeah, this will work, but I'd rather not use temp files. If there's no other way to go about it, I'll go this route. Thanks for the suggestions.